# Carrossel de imagem javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou implementando um carrossel de imagens em javascript, porém a transição de imagens não funciona e fica mostrando somente a primeira imagem "01.jpg".

script.js

```
$(function(){

$('#slide img:eq(0)').addClass("ativo").show();
setInterval(slide,3000);

function slide(){

    //Se a proxima imagem existir
    if($('.ativo').next().length){

        //Esconde a 1ª img, remove a classe ativo, mostra a proxima img e adiciona a classe ativo nela
        $('.ativo').fadeOut().removeClass("ativo").next().fadeIn().addClass("ativo");

    }else{ //Se for a ultima img do carrosel

        //Dá fadeOut na img, remove a classe ativo
        $('.ativo').fadeOut().removeClass("ativo");
        //Mostra a 1ª img do carrosel
        $('#slide img:eq(0)').fadeIn().addClass("ativo");

    }

} });
```

inicial.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure id="slide">

<img src="armazenamento/galeria/01.jpg"/>
   <img src="armazenamento/galeria/02.jpg"/>
   <img src="armazenamento/galeria/03.jpg"/>
   <img src="armazenamento/galeria/04.jpg"/>
   <img src="armazenamento/galeria/05.jpg"/>
</figure>
```

estilo.css

```
#slide {
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px auto;
height: 333px;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
position: relative; }

#slide img {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
display: none;
left: 0; }
```

Comment: Não está faltando `/>` nesses `img src`?

Comment: Eu corrigi isso também, mas não resolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `size()` foi removida a partir da versão 3.0 do jQuery conforme [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/size/).

No lugar dela, para verificar se existe a próxima imagem você pode utilizar `length`.

A verificação deve ser: `if($('.ativo').next().length){`

> Como não sei qual versão do jQuery está usando, o problema pode ser esse. Testei aqui apenas substituindo `size()` por `length` e deu certo.

Comment: Estou usando o jquery 3.3.1 slim. Eu já havia tentado também usar o length(), porém sem sucesso. Onde eu posso estar errando?

Comment: Amigo, a sua dica deu certo! Usei o length no lugar do size, mas também tive que trocar a versão do jquery e utilizar a 3.4.1 para funcionar.